# Strategies for Handling Customized Text or String During Web Application Upgrade

Tags: html, web-applications

If you were creating a boxed web application that your customers can unwrap and install out of the box and you want to allow them to customize some, if not all, the text displayed, how would you handle the upgrade when the next version of your application ships?

One way to allow users to customize the text is to use resource files, like in Java, and use keys in the UI that get replaced when the HTML is generated.  The customer can then go into those files and edit the actual text.

One possible way to handle this when I upgrade is to compare the text resource files the customer has and not overwrite the lines where it has been changed.

Are there other better ways of doing this?  Consider this an open ended question.  For example, if you think the resource file idea is terrible and leads to problems during upgrade, suggest another approach.  Nothing is set in stone at the moment.  The only constraints are:
1.  Web application
2.  Allow customizable text
3.  Handle upgrade in a way that's not too expensive for the customer.  It's OK if the customer has to do some work to upgrade but it should be reasonable.  If he only changed one line of text, then he should just have to handle that one line.  It's not acceptable for upgrade to completely fail because he has changed one line of text.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of web language is this going to be made in? Its possible in most. Just a version of localisation. Common practice these days in all applications.

Answer (score 0):

Using resource files is great for localization, but not for customization. If you want to allow your customers to customize resource text, etc then a better alternative is to use a database resource provider. Rick Strahl has an outstanding article written on how to implement this kind of solution.

[http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/)

Then you can simply create an administrative front-end to allow values to be changed in the database.